# Check if object exists in the hierarchy using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following Entity Framework class with a column which is a foreign key to the primary key in the same table:

```
[Table("Items")]
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public long ItemID { get; set; }

    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    public long? ItemParentID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ItemParentID")]
    public virtual Item Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> Children { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping above works great and I am able to get all the children items in the `Children` property to the nth level simply by passing the `ItemParentID` and selecting the Items.

In my business logic I have `ParentItemID` and `ChildItemID` and I have to check whether the `ChildItemID` exists anywhere in the hierarchy within the `Children` items of ParentItemID, it can be present in the `ParentItems -> Children and -> their Children and -> their Children etc`.

I have tried the following lambda expression but it is working for two levels of child items only:

```
ParentItem.Children.Contains(context.Items.Where(x => x.ItemID == ChildItem).FirstOrDefault())
```

How can I achieve this by writing a simple LINQ or lambda statement which returns a bool value?

Comment: You need to recursively parse through all the sub-children.  I usually just create a static helper method to perform the query which isn't linq.  public Boolean GetChild(Item i){....}

Comment: @jdweng yes that is one way to do it but I was hoping for a solution within `Entity Framework` itself as it is already able to get all the child items to nth levelwithout wring any complex recursive `LINQ` statements..

Comment: Why do people think that recursive methods are complex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written the following recursive method to solve this:

```
public bool CheckIfChildItemExists(ICollection<Item> childItems, long childItemId)
{
    var isChildExisting = false;
    foreach (Item item in childItems)
    {
        if (item.Children.Contains(context.Items.Where(x => x.ItemID == childItemId && x.IsActive).FirstOrDefault()))
        {
            isChildExisting = true;
            return isChildExisting;
        }
        else
        {
            return CheckIfItemChildExists(item.Children, childItemId);
        }
    }
    return isChildExisting;
}
```

And then calling it like this:

```
bool isAccessible = CheckIfChildItemExists(ParentItem.Children, childItemId);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Best way to do it

Regardless of what your object is and for what table in the database the only thing you need to have is the primary key in the object.

### C# Code

```
var dbValue = EntityObject.Entry(obj).GetDatabaseValues();
if (dbValue != null)
{
   exist
}
```